# Null pointer expection creating EntityManagerFactory upgrading to Hibernate 5.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We create a EntityManagerFactory like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}"
      p:initialSize="${dbcp.initialSize}"
      p:maxTotal="${dbcp.maxActive}"
      p:maxIdle="${dbcp.maxIdle}"
      p:minIdle="${dbcp.minIdle}"
      p:maxWaitMillis="${dbcp.maxWait}"
      p:validationQuery="${dbcp.validationQuery}"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>
```

This works as expected in Hibernate 4. I upgraded to Hibernate 5.1.0 and started getting this exception:

**UPDATE: This is not a Hibernate 5 specific issue. This actually happens just upgrading from hiberate 4.2.5.Final to 4.3.5.Final**

```
WARN; May 22, 2016 9:7:34 PM; tid:17; | XmlWebApplicationContext refresh; Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationEx
ception: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [fp-core-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.Persiste
nceException: [PersistenceUnit: fp] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
ERROR; May 22, 2016 9:7:34 PM; tid:17; | ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext; Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [freedompop-core-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed
; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: freedompop] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: freedompop] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy.foundCircularAssociation(AbstractLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy.java:672) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker.visitAttributeDefinition(MetamodelGraphWalker.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker.visitAttributes(MetamodelGraphWalker.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker.visitCompositeDefinition(MetamodelGraphWalker.java:199) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker.visitCollectionIndex(MetamodelGraphWalker.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker.visitCollectionDefinition(MetamodelGraphWalker.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.walking.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker.visitCollection(MetamodelGraphWalker.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.spi.MetamodelDrivenLoadPlanBuilder.buildRootCollectionLoadPlan(MetamodelDrivenLoadPlanBuilder.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.<init>(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.CollectionLoader.<init>(CollectionLoader.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.CollectionLoader$Builder.byKey(CollectionLoader.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.buildNonBatchingLoader(AbstractBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.java:28) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.createBatchingOneToManyInitializer(BatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.createCollectionInitializer(OneToManyPersister.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:658) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:446) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

**Update2: Here is the persistence.xml as requested in comments:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="companyName" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"/>
</persistence>
```

The issue is clearly a null pointer exception but what is null? The error doesn't give any detail as to what is causing the null pointer exception. Any ideas on what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) ... problem is in stacktrace: *Error creating bean with name `entityManagerFactory` defined in class path resource [`freedompop-core-context.xml`]: **Invocation of init method failed***

Comment: @JordiCastilla Not sure about that, the exception is inside a Hibernate class itself: `AbstractLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy`.

Comment: @Tunaki - I think he's just trolling.

Comment: @Tunaki and David: I'm not trolling anybody and sorry if it seems, you say in your question you changed Hibernate version, I guess config settings must be changed in order to fix the `entityManager`, after you correct config with new version you will avoid `NPE`. But anyway IMHO a `NPE` is a `NPE` thus... this is a duplicate

Comment: @JordiCastilla `a NPE is a NPE thus... this is a duplicate` I can't help sighing on this.  The NPE is not caused by anything obvious that OP can control.  Treating it as duplicate by throwing that "how to fix NPE" question simply won't help.  It may be caused by changed API that expect you to set some new mandatory propery, or caused by incompatible versions of library etc, for which all sort of these possibility cannot be resolved by telling OP "what's NPE and how to fix it"

Comment: OP: Can you show us what's inside your persistence.xml? Just a recommendation for you to identify the problem: try to make the config as minimal as possible.  e.g. Just include one extremely simple entity class (in persistence.xml or hibernate mapping or control by package to scan etc) and try to make it work

Comment: @AdrianShum - I have updated the question with your request. Going to start hacking at this again tomorrow, will try your suggestions as best as possible. Huge application I am dealing with.

Comment: @DavidR It looks strange to me: You haven't told Hibernate where to find the entities (nothing in `persistence.xml`, no `packageToScan`, no hbm etc).  I guess there are some key settings you have missed out...

Comment: @AdrianShum - Sounds like I need to do some reading up on the persistence.xml? I have never used hibernate in this way... Just asked to upgrade to latest and got stuck on that error. Again it works in 4.2.5.Final so maybe somewhere in an earlier version it would assume something for you where now expects you to declare?

Comment: I used to do the OR mapping by annotation, and make use of `packageToScan` in `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.  Later versions of Spring (which you are using) allow you to do a "persistence.xml-less" setup